# Is there a better way to implement the 2-SUM algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Currently, I was trying to create a 2-SUM algorithm that would, given a set of around 1 million integers, find the number of target values *t* **(-10,000 <= t <= 10,000)**  that are formed by the sum of any two values *x,y* in the set.

I have no problem with 2-SUM for a single value of t, just by using hash-tables and finding for each hash entry *x* in the table if there exists another entry *t-x*. This will run in `O(N)` time.

But, now I have to find multiple values of t, from -10000 to 10000. If I just use a plain for-loop, then the runtime will now be `O(N^2)`.
I have tried this code, which brute-forces through all `t` from -10000 to 10000, but it simply runs too slow (~1hr. to execute).

So, my question is, are there any hints for better ways to handle the ~20,001 targets without having to brute-force through all 20,001 values?

Here is the code I used for my `O(N^2)` solution:

```
for(long long t = -10000; t <= 10000; t++)
{
  for(unordered_set<long long>::iterator it=S.begin(); it != S.end(); ++it)
  {
     long long value = *it;
     if((S.find(t-value) != S.end()) & (t-value != value))
     {
        values++;
        //cout << "Found pair target " << t << " " <<   value << " " << t-value << '\n';
        break;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `S` in line 3?

Comment: `are there any hints for better ways ` Yes, ensure your dataset is sorted first.

Comment: @user3437460 I have tried using the ordered `set` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) , but it has a logarithmic O(log N) access time. Do you know of any better hash-tables?

Comment: @erip S is the dataset (hash-table like) I used.

Comment: @PatrickYu If you are allowed to sort your dataset first, then sort it with an efficient algorithm like merge sort/quick sort which is `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Wait, so indexing in `unordered_map` only guarantees `O(1)` search time if the dataset is ordered initially?

Comment: No, but having a sorted map ensured O(log n) search in a binary search. However, I think there's a better way with a Bloom filter.

Comment: If you are not allowed to sort first, then ensure it is sorted as you input the numbers.  Just do a binary insertion. It is probably the most efficient approach for this.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will be sure to try sorted inputs.

Comment: Also, thanks everyone for your tips, I just solved the problem using buckets!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who has helped!

I solved the problem by partitioning the input into multiple "buckets", that is, I would sort the dataset and then split it into buckets of intervals of 10,000. So, the smallest 10k numbers go into 1st bucket, next 10k to 2nd, and so forth.... I would split it into  so when I have to search for the entry *t-x*, I will search in my 10,000 numbers rather than all 1,000,000 numbers.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to use an ***ordered set*** (if values are unique, or ordered array / list if you care for duplicates).

Then, you search for a matching pair for your values using the following method:

> 1. For each *Val* (-10000, -9999, ...)
> 2. Let *iS* be 0
> 3. Let *iE* be length - 1
> 4. While *(S[iS] + S[iE]) != Val*
>      4.1 *(S[iS] + S[iE]) > Val* : Binary Search in (*iS -> iE - 1*) for the maximum value, lower or equal to *(Val - S[iS])* and set iE to match.
>      4.2 *(S[iS] + S[iE]) < Val* : Binary Search in (*iS +1 -> iE*) for the minimum value, higher or equal to *(Val - S[iE])* and set iS to match.
>      4.3 If *iS > iE*, *Val* doesn't exist.

This gives you **O(n log(n))** for sorting, and **O(m n)** (*m* is 20001 for -10000 -> 10000) for searching although realistically, the searching will perform much better then *O(m n)*. The entire solution is *O(m n)* due to *m > log(n)*.

It can be further optimized by using a map of matched values and on each iteration, after a match is found, advance *iE* till *(S[iS] + S[iE]) > maxValue* (10000) and marking all sums as found, then there are less iterations in outer loop.

Comment: Isn't the `while` loop O(N) because in worst case,`iS` and `iE` will traverse the list until they meet at the midpoint?

Comment: @PatrickYu - Yes, I was just thinking about this. The answer is inaccurate - will revise.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have already suggested, if you want a "best effort" approach (meaning that it may not be the best, but still good enough), you can sort your data and use std::lower_bound for searching.

The [std::lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) function is implemented as a binary search, which means that in the worst case, for 1000000 integers you'll be having 20 comparisons to find a match. If you do this inside of a -10000..10000 loop you'll get 20000*20 = 400000 comparisons, which should take far less than an hour (my guess is a few minutes, depending on CPU power).

The map::find on an unordered_set is a linear search, that means that in the worst case you're going to have 20000*1000000 = 20000000000 comparisons, which is 50000 times worse.

You could improve on a binary search (e.g. by seeing how "close" you're to your target and switching to linear search from there if you're under a specific difference in value) but I don't think that would speed up the search that much.

There are other ways, probaly faster (maybe you could discard duplicates using 15625 integers with 64 bit precision and setting the bit matching the value in your dataset, giving you and O(n) time for the setup and an O(1) for the lookup, but you're going to need two sets, one for positive values, the other for negative), but they're going to be much more difficult to implement.